# Is there any way to use placeholder or error drawables with remote views using Picasso,Glide or any

Tags: android, picasso, android-glide, remoteview

**I am not able to give any placeholder or error drawable in remoteview using Picasso.**

```
Picasso
.with(context)
.load(imageurl)
.into(remoteview,R.id.icon,NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
```

**Even used this it is giving me error**

```
Picasso
.with(context)
.load(imageurl)
.placeholder(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.error(R.drawable.error)
.into(remoteview,R.id.icon,NOTIFICATION_ID,notification);
```

*(Cannot use placeholder or error drawables with remote views.)*

> > What should i do ?

Comment: Putting image in imageview (xml) can act as a placeholder.

`android:src="drawable/myimage"`

Comment: but if i need to show some different image in case of error then what to do @jitinsharma

Answer (score 0):

You can set placeholder via xml `android:src="drawable/myimage"` jitinsharma suggested, and for error image inside error picass callback change it with another drawable resource: `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.myErrorImage);`

Is that solve your problem?

p.s. still interesting for me, why Picasso can't work with remote views.